# How to clamp small values to zero in theano

Tags: theano

I know the theano clip function, but what I want to do is different: I have a vector and if an entry is small, but not zero, I want to make it zero. Entries greater than the given threshold will remain unchanged.
Is there a way to do that in theano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clip the values of a vector below a specific threshold to zero with the following code snippet:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

x = T.ivector('x')
threshold = 5  # change accordingly
x_clipped = x * (x > threshold)

f = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=x_clipped)

print(f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
```